# How to find out why Linux Mint won't connect to wifi?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

On Linux Mint 20.1, how can I find out why can't I connect to the Wifi? I have wifi tethered from Android phone and I tried to connect as:

```
oem@oem-Aspire-E1-572:~$ nmcli d wifi list | grep Galaxy
        0E:66:A8:6F:04:A1  Galaxy A419596            Infra  6     117 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA2      
oem@oem-Aspire-E1-572:~$ nmcli d wifi connect 0E:66:A8:6F:04:A1 password aaaa1111
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.
```

I just edited the password to this post. But how can I debug why Mint won't find the network?

Comment: Can you show how have you tried to resolve the issue? That's always helpful so folks don't duplicate effort.

Answer (score 0):

The connect command is:

```
wifi d wifi connect (B)SSID ...
```

So, if your network is named `Galaxy A419596` (as it appears in your question), you need to connect with

```
wifi d wifi connect "Galaxy A419596"
```

Comment: I got still a pop up to my screen: "activation of a network connection failed". But now my wifi is on according to terminal.